# Laravel Update method return 406 error

Tags: laravel-5, http-status-code-406

My update method is working in localhost, but got 406 error on the server, i have tried the .htaccess method, but it is not working.

And i found it not all of the data cannot update, only some of it return me 406 error.

here is my code:

```
public function update(UpdateUserRequest $request, $id)
    {
        //
        $user = User::findOrFail($id);

        $user_detail = [];
        if($user->id != Auth::user()->id && $user->role_id != 1 && $user->role_id != 2) {
          $user_detail = [
            'surname'     => $request->surname ,
            'givenname'   => $request->givenname ,
            'gender'      => $request->gender ,
            'birthday'    => $request->birthday ,
            'ic_no'       => $request->ic_no ,
            'address'     => $request->address ,
            'bank_acc_no' => $request->bank_acc_no ,
            'bank_name'   => $request->bank_name ,
            'role_id'     => $request->role
          ];
        }
        else if ($user->id == Auth::user()->id) {
          $user_detail = [
            'surname'     => $request->surname ,
            'givenname'   => $request->givenname ,
            'gender'      => $request->gender ,
            'birthday'    => $request->birthday ,
            'ic_no'       => $request->ic_no ,
            'address'     => $request->address ,
            'bank_acc_no' => $request->bank_acc_no ,
            'bank_name'   => $request->bank_name
          ];
        }

        $user->update($user_detail);

        ...

        Session::flash('success_message', trans('text.text_user_detail_update_sucessfully'));
        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

I also found that even i comment all of the code inside the Update method, the browser still give me 406 error.

Anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: See [here](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/error-numbers/406-error) !!

Comment: @Maraboc Godaddy sharehosting is not allow to turn off